# recyclerview dosen't appear when I type in edittext and appears when I hide keyboard in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have an activity for searching in firebase, it contains edit text for typing the text and button when I press the button The results supposed to appear in the recyclerview but when I press the button the first time nothing appears unless I hide the keyboard and when I press the second time nothing appears unless the keyboard shows. Is there a solution for this problem?

Code of activity

```
public class FindDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference db;
FirebaseHelper helper;
MyAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView rv;
EditText findETxt;
Button findBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_data);
    //SETUP RECYCLER
    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvsearch);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    //INITIALIZE FIREBASE DB
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Database");
    findETxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.findETxt);
    findBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find_btn);    
}

public void search(View view) {
    helper = new FirebaseHelper(db);
    final String s = findETxt.getText().toString();
    //ADAPTER
    adapter = new MyAdapter(FindDataActivity.this, helper.retrieveSearch(s));
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);           
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

}
```

This is code of firebase

```
public class FirebaseHelper {
DatabaseReference db;
Boolean saved=null;
Boolean saved1=null;

ArrayList<Paints> paints=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> keys=new ArrayList<>();

public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
    this.db = db;
}
//WRITE IF NOT NULL
public Boolean save(Paints paint)
{
    if(paint==null)
    {
        saved=false;
    }else
    {
        try
        {
            db.child("items").push().setValue(paint);
            saved=true;
        }catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved=false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}


// IN STATE OF UPDATE
public Boolean save1(Paints paint,String k)
{
    if(paint==null)
    {
        saved1=false;
    }else
    {
        try
        {
            db.child("items").child(k).setValue(paint);
            saved1=true;
        }catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved1=false;
        }
    }
    return saved1;
}


//IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    paints.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Paints spacecraft=ds.getValue(Paints.class);
        paints.add(spacecraft);
    }
}
//READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST
public ArrayList<Paints> retrieve() {
    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return paints;
}

//READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST OF KEYS IN CASE OF ALL DATA
public ArrayList<String> retrieve1() {
    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchDataKeys(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchDataKeys(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return keys;
}

//IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST WITH ALL KEYS
private void fetchDataKeys(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    keys.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        keys.add(ds.getKey());
    }
}

//READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST FOR SEARCH ITEMS IN CASE OF SEARCHING ABOUT ITEM
public ArrayList<Paints> retrieveSearch(final String item) {
    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchDataSearch(dataSnapshot,item);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchDataSearch(dataSnapshot,item);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return paints;
}

//IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST WITH ALL PAINTS
private void fetchDataSearch( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String item)
{
    paints.clear();

    //sorting and searching
    final DatabaseReference myRef = db.child("items");
    Query query = myRef.orderByChild("type").startAt(item)
            .endAt(item + "\uf8ff");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Paints paint=messageSnapshot.getValue(Paints.class);

                paints.add(paint);
                //Toast.makeText(FindDataActivity.this, "found " + type + " unit: " + unit + " price " + price, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

//READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST OF KEYS IN CASE OF SEARCH ITEM
public ArrayList<String> retrieve1Search(final String item) {
    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchDataKeysSearch(dataSnapshot,item);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchDataKeysSearch(dataSnapshot,item);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return keys;
}

//IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST WITH KEYS IN STATE OF SEARCH
private void fetchDataKeysSearch(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String item)
{
    keys.clear();

    //sorting and searching
    final DatabaseReference myRef = db.child("items");
    Query query = myRef.orderByChild("type").startAt(item)
            .endAt(item + "\uf8ff");

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
       {

                keys.add(messageSnapshot.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}

}
```

code for Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
Context c;
ArrayList<Paints> paints=new ArrayList<Paints>();
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Paints> paints) {
    this.c = c;
    this.paints = paints;
    //this.keys=keys;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v=LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final  Paints paint=paints.get(position);
    //final String ss=keys.get(position);

    holder.typeTxt.setText(paint.getType());
    holder.unitTxt.setText(paint.getUnit());
    holder.priceTxt.setText(String.valueOf(paint.getPrice()));
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int pos) {
            //OPEN DETAI ACTIVITY
            openDetailActivity(paint.getType(),paint.getUnit(),paint.getPrice());
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return paints.size();
}
//OPEN DETAIL ACTIVITY
private void openDetailActivity(String type,String unit, Double price)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(c,DetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("TYPE_KEY",type);
    i.putExtra("UNIT_KEY",unit);
    i.putExtra("PRICE_KEY", price);
    //i.putExtra("K_KEY",s);

    c.startActivity(i);
}
}
```

code for viewholder

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
TextView typeTxt,unitTxt,priceTxt;
ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    typeTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.typeTxt);
    unitTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.unitTxt);
    priceTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceTxt);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
{
    this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(this.getLayoutPosition());
}
}
```

Comment: show your code  what you have written

Comment: I updated my question with code